# display:table in <ul><li> to get vertical-align:middle of <a> item produces Chrome/Chromium issue?

Tags: css, firefox, html-lists, vertical-alignment, chromium

On a `<nav>` bar layout I used `display: table` on the parent `<ul><li>` item and `display: table-cell` on the child `<a>` item to be able to use `vertical-align: middle` on the `<a>` item. (Some items are multiline, so setting `line-height` is not a possibility).

On Chrome/Chromium I get the whole `<nav>` bar 'shifting' to the right when I hover over menu items (only when they have children).

This doesn't happen on Firefox.

Load the jfiddle in both browsers and see:

http://jsfiddle.net/qcQKP/2/

Does anyone have any ideas why this happens? / how to get around it?

Thanks!

Comment: You realise that you don't really need any Javascript code to achieve menus like this, right? it can be done with pure CSS `:hover`.

Comment: @Spudley, thanks, yes I do realize this can be done with pure CSS, but this is legacy and rewriting is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the left shift is due to your first level li's being floated left.  If you change these to table-cells as well you should stop the shift:

```
nav > ul > li {
    font-size: 11px; /* 11px */
    position: relative;
    max-width: 16em;
    height: 36px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/qcQKP/3/)